# How do I make my div's lined up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my div's to line up on the top, but not line up at the bottom. This allows for flexibility of content:

```css
/* font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* end of font */

/* clear settings */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */
  #nav {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009ACD;
  }
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */
  #primary_nav_wrap
{
    width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 3%;
    top: 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 50;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:7.5px 9px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */
  #course_div {
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #course_img {
    width: 216px;
    height: 121.5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  #course_info {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 205.5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  a .course_main {
     text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 204px;
  }

  .course_main {
    width: 216px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
  }

/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>

      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

    <!-- info nav -->
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Business</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Law</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
      <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intuit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Influence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Motivation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
      <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
      <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
      <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Black & White</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dieting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
      <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Arabic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Music</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
      <li><a href="#">Vocal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
</ul>


</ul>
</nav>
    <!-- end of info nav -->

    <div id='course_div'>

   <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, I have two divs, but they are not lined up. How do I line up the divs on the top? I've tried the *flex* property, but nothing is working...

Comment: See what happens when you put "Excel" instead of "Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel" ;)

Comment: @CalvT that doesn't solve anything. OP was likely replicated a multi-line description and reducing to a single word or line likely won't be an option.

Comment: @hungerstar fair enough, but I was trying to point out that the reason they weren't lined up was because one of the lines was double, and the other single. This shows that they were lining themselves at the bottom.

Comment: Everyone is making the same mistake. The divs still need to be able to wrap and have the same margin-bottom regardless of the height of the div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to add `float: left;` to the anchor tags in `#course_div` and then target every anchor element after the 5th anchor element with `nth-child()` to clear the floated elements before it.

```css
#course_div a {
  float: left;
}
#course_div a:nth-child(5n+6) {
   clear: left;
}
```

**SIDE NOTE:** `#course_info` is being used repeatedly and should be a CSS class, `.course_info`.

```css
/* font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* end of font */

/* clear settings */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */
  #nav {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009ACD;
  }
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */
  #primary_nav_wrap
{
    width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 3%;
    top: 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 50;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:7.5px 9px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */
  #course_div {
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #course_img {
    width: 216px;
    height: 121.5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  #course_info {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 205.5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  a .course_main {
     text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 204px;
  }

  .course_main {
    width: 216px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
  }

#course_div a {
  float: left;
}
#course_div a:nth-child(5n+6) {
   clear: left;
}
/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>

      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

    <!-- info nav -->
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Business</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Law</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
      <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intuit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Influence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Motivation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
      <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
      <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
      <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Black & White</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dieting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
      <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Arabic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Music</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
      <li><a href="#">Vocal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
</ul>


</ul>
</nav>
    <!-- end of info nav -->

    <div id='course_div'>

   <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

display flex, does the job.

See the code below with your updated display propery.

```css
/* font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* end of font */

/* clear settings */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */

#nav {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #009ACD;
}
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */

#primary_nav_wrap {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 3%;
  top: 5px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 50;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 7.5px 9px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */

#course_div {
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex; /* ADD YOUR FLEX DISPLAY PROPERTY HERE */
  flex-flow: wrap;
  
}
#course_img {
  width: 216px;
  height: 121.5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
}
#course_info {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 205.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
a .course_main {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 204px;
}
.course_main {
  width: 216px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hacked Genius</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
  <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- nav -->
  <div id='nav'>

  </div>
  <!-- end of nav -->

  <!-- info nav -->
  <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Development</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Game Development</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Databases</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Business</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Finance</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Communications</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Management</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Strategy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Operations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Project Management</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Business Law</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Home Business</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Industry</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Media</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
            <li><a href="#">Hardware</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
              <li><a href="#">Google</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">SAP</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Intuit</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Oracle</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
                <li><a href="#">Leadership</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Career Development</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Happiness</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Creativity</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Influence</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Motivation</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <li><a href="#">Design</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
                  <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">User Experience</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Game Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fashion</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>

              <li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Branding</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
                      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Travel</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>

                  <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Landscape</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Black & White</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video Design</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
                          <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yoga</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dieting</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dance</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Meditation</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>

                      <li><a href="#">Language</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
                            <li><a href="#">French</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Japanese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chinese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Russian</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Latin</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Arabic</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Italian</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Music</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
                              <li><a href="#">Vocal</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Music Software</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>

                          <li><a href="#">Academics</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
                            </ul>


    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of info nav -->

  <div id='course_div'>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great answer, but the divs need to wrap. Right now, they are doing [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Lyb.png) and are supposed to be doing the [following](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0JAZ.png) wrapping effect.

Comment: the you should add `flex-flow: wrap;` update my answer

Comment: Your answer is very similar to @hungerstar. But, his solution doesn't make the links leak. If you hover your cursor below one of the divs, a link still appears...

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.course_main` class:

```css
/* font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* end of font */

/* clear settings */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */

#nav {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #009ACD;
}
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */

#primary_nav_wrap {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 3%;
  top: 5px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 50;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 7.5px 9px;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */

#course_div {
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#course_img {
  width: 216px;
  height: 121.5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
}
#course_info {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 205.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
a .course_main {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 204px;
}
.course_main {
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 216px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hacked Genius</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
  <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- nav -->
  <div id='nav'>

  </div>
  <!-- end of nav -->

  <!-- info nav -->
  <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Development</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Game Development</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Databases</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Business</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Finance</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Communications</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Management</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Strategy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Operations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Project Management</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Business Law</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Home Business</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Industry</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Media</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
            <li><a href="#">Hardware</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
              <li><a href="#">Google</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">SAP</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Intuit</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Oracle</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
                <li><a href="#">Leadership</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Career Development</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Happiness</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Creativity</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Influence</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Motivation</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <li><a href="#">Design</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
                  <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">User Experience</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Game Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fashion</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>

              <li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Branding</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
                      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Travel</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>

                  <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Landscape</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Black & White</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video Design</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
                          <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yoga</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dieting</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dance</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Meditation</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>

                      <li><a href="#">Language</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
                            <li><a href="#">French</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Japanese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chinese</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Russian</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Latin</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Arabic</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Italian</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Music</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
                              <li><a href="#">Vocal</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Music Software</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>

                          <li><a href="#">Academics</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
                            </ul>


    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of info nav -->

  <div id='course_div'>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href='#'>
      <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

        <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but it's doing [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yl9z.png). How do I make the links the proper size?

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery soluction can be jQuery.equalHeights:

https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights

It will calculate the height of your selector and set the same height to all the elements within your selector.

e.g.

```
<div class="test">
    This is one line of text.
</div>

<div class="test">
    This is three lines of text.<br>
    This is three lines of text.<br>
    This is three lines of text.<br>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .test{border: solid 1px #f00};
</style>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.test').equalHeights();
   });
</script>
```

Another solution can be the use of flexbox, example found here: http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `display: inline-block` to `display: inline-table` in the `.course_main` div in CSS

```css
/* font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* end of font */

/* clear settings */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */
  #nav {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009ACD;
  }
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */
  #primary_nav_wrap
{
    width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 3%;
    top: 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 50;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:7.5px 9px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */
  #course_div {
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #course_img {
    width: 216px;
    height: 121.5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  #course_info {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 205.5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  a .course_main {
     text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 204px;
  }

  .course_main {
    width: 216px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 30px;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
  }

/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>

      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

    <!-- info nav -->
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Business</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Law</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
      <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intuit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Influence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Motivation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
      <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
      <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
      <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Black & White</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dieting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
      <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Arabic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Music</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
      <li><a href="#">Vocal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
</ul>


</ul>
</nav>
    <!-- end of info nav -->

    <div id='course_div'>

   <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Hi
          </div> </div></a>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best [answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/53qqu.png) so far. Is there a way to make the bottom part of the divs have the same margin-bottom? They don't need to end at the same place, but is there a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Hello and thanks for deeming this as a good answer.  Unfortunately, I do not know how you can achieve that using inline-table.  The only thing that comes in mind is changing the padding-bottom and increase/decrease padding bottom pixel size until it lines up.  This is not a great practice but that's the only solution I can think of.